# How can you fix the bootstrap nav bar to the viewport when content is wider?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and have page content that may be significantly wider than the browser screen. The Bootstrap nav bar will resize as I change the size of the window, but if I scroll to the right it maintains a fixed width with left: 0.

I am looking for a way to have the nav bar remain visible as I scroll beyond the initial window size.

Here is a code example that has the issue:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->



<!-- TODO IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<!-- <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script> <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script> <![endif]-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary bg-custom fixed-top-zzzz" style="z-index: 10000; padding: 0 5px;">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>

<ul class="navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="/" class="nav-link">link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div style="width:4000px">
Wide div breaks bav
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you restricted to Bootstrap 3? Or can you upgrade to Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Yeah, should be easy to upgrade (knock on wood).

Comment: Lol, if its possible, then you wouldn't have to do much to fix this, as with Bootsrap 4 will basically give you exactly the behavior you need. I'll add an answer with the example just so you can see how it behaves

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is basically just by using Bootstrap v4 instead of v3, I did make some additional changes, namely:

- Removed the `pull-right` class and added `ml-auto`
- Changed class `fixed-top-zzzz` to just `fixed-top`
- Added `margin-top: 50px` to container div to be able to see content behind navbar

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-primary bg-custom fixed-top" style="z-index: 10000; padding: 0 5px;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>

  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="/" class="nav-link">link1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="/" class="nav-link">link2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="/" class="nav-link">link3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div style="width:4000px; margin-top: 50px">
  Wide div breaks bav 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: This expands the nav bar to fill the width of the document, but creates a problem where nav elements scroll off the screen. My intent in the question (sorry if it wasn't clear) was to have the hav elements stay fixed relative to the viewport, so as the document scrolled left/right, you'd always be able to see the navigation.

Comment: Don't really understand, in this case for example, the `link` element stays at the left of the navbar; but its always visible when you scroll to the sides

Comment: My mistake, I was trying this locally and it was polluted with some other CSS I didn't think was included.

Comment: Oh, well, hope it helped you at least :)

Comment: I realize upon further testing, this works on desktop, but doesn't work on mobile, at least when I tell Chrome to be an iPhone. The nav extends to 100% of the doc, but the links float to the far right of the document (off screen).

Comment: I'd suggest you try again, If I test it on mobile it actually works the same way, I mean, I did't setup the example so the navbar collapses, but it behaves the same, eveything stays on the screen while I'm able to scroll

Comment: @parker https://imgur.com/a/LbSX34F if you see that image, I have scrolled sideways but the navbar stays the same

Comment: This turned out to be a Chrome bug, though I had to make some small tweaks per another comment to get the viewport properly set when the content extended beyond it.

Comment: Oh of course, the `meta` tag, that should always be included to help with responsiveness

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment in the previous answer, the .navbar-fixed-top class seems like it should help you get your nav stay fixed as you scroll horizontally (or vertically).

https://www.bootply.com/a2nMrbqqzv

Comment: This works on desktop Chrome, but not on mobile (simulated in Chrome).

Comment: strange, seems to work for me. if you can provide a jsfiddle, codepen, etc. I can try helping

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug here, though I had to add the following line in the header to avoid Mobile Safari from zooming out and showing the desktop experience:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">